# Unity game engine having camera follow script transform change depending on car selected script?

Tags: unity-game-engine, selector, unityscript

```
OVERALL GOAL: Have the camera change target to the selected car
```

I'm new to the unity game engine and got a bit of a problem.

So, I have a successful car selector which changes between cars and starts the match with that car. Everything there works. The only issue is that my "CarCameraScript" has a transform variable which is always 1 of the 3 cars. I want it to change dependant on the selected car.

Here is the look at the code of the CarCameraScript

```c#
#pragma strict
var car : Transform;
var distance: float = 6.4;
var height: float = 1.4;
var rotationDamping : float = 3.0;
var heightDamping: float = 2.0;
var zoomRatio : float = 0.5;
var DefaultFOV : float = 60;
private var rotationVector : Vector3;

function Start () {

}

function LateUpdate () {
var wantedAngel = rotationVector.y;
var wantedHeight = car.position.y + height;
var myAngel = transform.eulerAngles.y;
var myHeight = transform.position.y;
myAngel = Mathf.LerpAngle(myAngel,wantedAngel,rotationDamping*Time.deltaTime);
myHeight = Mathf.Lerp(myHeight,wantedHeight,heightDamping*Time.deltaTime);
var currentRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,myAngel,0);
transform.position = car.position;
transform.position -= currentRotation*Vector3.forward*distance;
transform.position.y = myHeight;
transform.LookAt(car);
}
function FixedUpdate () {
var localVilocity = car.InverseTransformDirection(car.rigidbody.velocity);
if (localVilocity.z<-0.5) {
rotationVector.y = car.eulerAngles.y + 180;
} else {
rotationVector.y = car.eulerAngles.y;
}
var acc = car.rigidbody.velocity.magnitude;
camera.fieldOfView = DefaultFOV + acc*zoomRatio;
}
```

This is what it looks like on the side panel.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYJP7.jpg

The area that says none (transform) is the place that should be variable dependant on the currently selected car.

Now, Here is my other script being the CharacterSelectScript

```c#
#pragma strict
//this is the currently selected Player. Also the one that will be saved to PlayerPrefs
var selectedPlayer : int = 0;

function Update() 
{ 
if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0)) {
    var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
    var hit : RaycastHit;

    if (Physics.Raycast (ray, hit, 100))
        {
                // The pink text is where you would put the name of the object you want to click on (has attached collider).

                 if(hit.collider.name == "Player1") 
            SelectedCharacter1(); //Sends this click down to a function called "SelectedCharacter1(). Which is where all of our stuff happens.

                if(hit.collider.name == "Player2")
                SelectedCharacter2();

                if(hit.collider.name == "Player3")
                SelectedCharacter3();
        } 
        else
        {
        return;               
        }
    } 
}

function SelectedCharacter1() {
    Debug.Log ("Character 1 SELECTED"); //Print out in the Unity console which     character was selected.
    selectedPlayer = 1;
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("selectedPlayer", (selectedPlayer));
}

function SelectedCharacter2() {
    Debug.Log ("Character 2 SELECTED");
    selectedPlayer = 2;
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("selectedPlayer", (selectedPlayer));
}

function SelectedCharacter3() {
    Debug.Log ("Character 3 SELECTED");
    selectedPlayer = 3;
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("selectedPlayer", (selectedPlayer));
}
```

How would I get it so that the SelectedPlayer changes the transform in the first script?
Any ideas?

I also have the prefab script which probably isnt important.
Also, should I join both scripts into one?

```c#
OVERALL GOAL: Have the camera change target to the selected car
```

Comment: Mate, why didn´t you update your question instead of opening another one? they topic is similar. Reference here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19893598/change-value-of-transform-variable-in-unity. Also if the previous answer help you please accept it or made a comment so other people could benefit.

Comment: Regarding your problem. Look at this asset: KGF Camera System, it will help you do exactly what you want and you will save a lot of work hours, and you could use it for other related camera tasks in your game. https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#/content/6867