# Change value of Transform variable in Unity

Tags: variables, unity-game-engine, transform, unityscript

I have a camera which follows a car when a player is driving. The issue is the car : transform variable in the UnityScript looks like this

```
var car : Transform;
```

Which means I would have to drag the transform onto the little box in the side panel to assign it.

Is it possible to assign this variable within the code like:

```
var car : Transform = Player1;

//BTW Player1 is the transform I want
```

The reason why it needs to be changed is in the code I want it to change between
    Player1
    Player2
    Player3

dependant on the currently selected one (i already coded this part)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how and when you want to do it. From your Camera class you can do something like:

```
var car : Transform;

public void ChangePlayer(string playerName) {
  GameObject playerGO = GameObject.Find(playerName);

  if(playerGO != null)
    car = playerGO.transform;
}
```